# TextField "rejected" signal?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

It has [accepted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#accepted-signal) signal. But I don't see `rejected` signal (i.e. user pressed Esc key) anywhere.

Am I missing something? If not, is there some workaround?

`Qt` 5.11, `Quick Controls 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is only to detect if the `Escape key` is pressed then use [Keys](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html).

```
TextInput {
    text: "Text"
    onAccepted: console.log("accepted")
    Keys.onEscapePressed: console.log("escaped")
}
```